# Xcode Provisioning Profile Expiring

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to clear a couple non-fatal errors from a couple projects.  They are both "Target Integrity" "Provisioning profile is expiring: . . . ".

Yet, I don't have the Provisioning profile that's expiring as a part of the project in any way. Can anyone tell me why it might be giving me an error like this for a Provisioning profile that is being used only by a different project?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest that you just ignore this warning.

Comment: I have the same problem.Just open Keychain Access, delete all the certificates and then create and add it again.

Answer (score 39):

Had the same problem. This is how to fix it:

Open Xcode > Preferences > Accounts

Click 'View Details' on the relevant account, and you'll see all associated provisioning profiles will open in a list. Sort the list by expiration date to find expired profiles, and for each one right click and choose 'show in finder'. Then you can simply delete it.

When you delete an expired profile in the finder it immediately disappears from Xcode and from the warnings panel.

Comment: This answer is a better solution for the problem. No need to install plugins or download utilities....

Comment: In XCode 7, if you've already deleted the provisioning profile using Keychain, 'show in finder' doesn't work, but you can press "Download All", restart XCode and it will accomplish this as well.

Comment: I have the same problem, I deleted everything, every profile, from finder, and the Warning still displays. Not a solution.

Comment: This method works. However, the "Provisioning profile is expiring: . . . " warning won't disappear until you quit xCode and restart.

Answer (score 20):

You can find your provisioning profiles in

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

There you can see all your provisioning profiles, but it's difficult to know which one is which because they are named with a UUID.

However, you can install this QuickLook plugin to see details about each profile and delete the ones that are expired:
https://github.com/chockenberry/Provisioning

The warning disappears instantly from Xcode after you delete the profile.

EDIT:
An easier method to clean up old profiles may be to download iPhone Configuration Utility from here:
http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility

It gives you a nice overview over you installed profiles and they can be deleted as well.

Comment: Going to this folder worked for me. but i had to delete all provisioning profiles and refresh my developer accounts (and hence download the existing and valid profiles). Xcode was pointing to a previosly deleted account's profile.

Answer (score 7):

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details

Then select that particular provisioning profile and click refresh button.

If you are still having warning then go to
https://developer.apple.com and 
select provisioning profile and click edit and then done. After that do the refresh procedure described before in X-Code

Comment: I deleted all my old ones in the developer portal and then went to: Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details and simply hit refresh and all expired and warnings are gone.

Answer (score 7):

`sigh manage -e` to delete all expired profiles

`sigh repair` will renew all profiles (requires login)

https://github.com/fastlane/sigh

Answer (score 2):

One liner here. No need to download plugins, utilities and all that crap.

```
ls | grep -l 'com.companyname.AppName' ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.mobileprovision | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I simply went into my Developer's account and renewed the expiring provisioning profile, even though I don't need/use it any more.  Error is gone.